# Firebase Reset Password Link (Not sending/Did not receive)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the reset password link for my app (using exactly the same firebase code provided at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users). It works well when I tried it using a gmail account that I have registered previously on the app (I received the reset password link on gmail and able to change for a new password). However, when I tried it with other email domains (like professional work or school domains e.g @mycompany.com or @school.edu), it does not seem to receive the email (not in junk/spam too). It is very weird because I do receive the 'email verification' link (from firebase) using other domains when I registered using the app but not when I tried to reset the password? Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Hey @Anon124. Any update here?

Answer (score 5):

As an FYI, currently in Jan 2023, Microsoft 365 business blocks these emails from ever reaching the target mailbox, even if you change the SMTP settings in firebase.

They still appear in your own SMTP sent section, they just never get delivered by MS.

**Solution**:
Use the admin SDK to get the reset link, and sent the email by yourself with your own SMTP server.

If you're using a language that doesn't have a firebase SDK, you can use the identity platform API to get a reset code:
[Identity Platform Docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/sendOobCode)

Comment: same for me too

Comment: So what's the solution to this?

Comment: I even got official word that Microsoft block all their customers from these mails (Basically blaming Google's servers): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/firebase-authentication-emails-are-blocked-by-office-365/m-p/3750188
Still no solution for me, cause own SMTP doesn't deliver at all (not even to @gmail) for some reason.

Comment: I updated my answer, but tldr get the reset code from the admin SDK then send the email yourself

Answer (score 1):

**Open firebase console goto Authentication then click on Templates > Password Reset then copy given email address** (it seems like, 'noreply@YOUR-PROJECT-NAME.firebaseapp.com') **then open your Gmail account and paste that email id in search section the tap on 'view message > move to not spam'**

This will surly help you
Thanks
Meet Patel

Answer (score 0):

If the code is the same and you don't get an error message, it is extremely likely that the email gets blocked somewhere along to the way to the target mailbox. You'd have to reach out to the system administrator and see if they can find the message somewhere in *their* spam filters, and ask them to modify the configuration of those to no longer block these messages.

Answer (score 0):

As ganey stated, the problem is that certain email filters such as MS 365 do not accept mails that contain links that are not in pair with the sender domain.

The solution is to add a customized action url that points to the same domain as your sender domain.

Then you need to redirect from that url to the url generated by firebase.

**Note:**
If you do this in react or another SPA, don't forget to append the query params.

[image]

Comment: Even after doing this with my custom domain wstill have the issue